# Linux Deploy - Fail to make disk image

Tags: root-access, samsung-galaxy-s-4, linux

I am trying to use [Linux Deploy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.meefik.linuxdeploy) on my rooted Galaxy S4 with stock Android 4.4 rom. But when I press install:

```
Updating configuration file ... done
>>> begin install
Checking mount points ... done
Checking installation path ... done
Making new disk image (1023 MB) ... fail
<<< end: install
```

I have already checked root permissions, tried to install in internal with `/storage/emulated/0` and `/storage/emulated/legacy`, I have also tried to modify the image size but same results, how can I solve that?

Comment: try installing in /storage/sdcard1/kali

Comment: In my device I don't have /storage/sdcard1, I tried /storage/sdcard0/linux but it doesn't work

Comment: It seems a problem related to Samsung's Touchwiz roms, on Cyanogenmod 11 the software works. Maybe it's related to Knox oe selinux?

Answer (score 1):

It's related with the touchwiz kernel, beacuse when I flashed adam kernel it started working. I think it has to do with selinux set on enforcing